# spring-data-jpa implements repository for you

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

### spring-data-jpa implements repository

---

I just started working with *Spring-boot* and *Accessing-data-jpa*, I decided to have a look at one of the guides provided by https://spring.io. The guide I decided to look at is [accessing-data-jpa](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/). I followed it to the end and than ran my application. To my supprise I was presented with an errormessage.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property name found for type User!
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:77)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:329)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:309)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:272)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:243)
at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:76)
```

So seems easy what the problem is. Somewhere it's looking for the property "name" in my User class. But I don't actually use a property "name" anywhere.

My Repository interface:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
   List<User> findByName(String userName);
}
```

My User class:

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long userID;
    private LocalDateTime joinDate;
    private String userName;
    private String email;

    protected User(){}

    public User(String userName){
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("User[id=%d, userName=%s, email= %s]",userID, userName,email);
    }
}
```

The application class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner demo(UserRepository repository){
        return (args) -> {
            //Save a few Users
            repository.save(new User("Niek"));
            repository.save(new User("Costas"));
            repository.save(new User("Eric"));
            repository.save(new User("Philip"));
            repository.save(new User("Barry"));

            //Fetch all Users
            log.info("Users Found With findAll()");
            log.info("--------------------------");
            for(User user: repository.findAll()){
                log.info(user.toString());
            }
            log.info("");

            //Fetch one User
            log.info("User found With findOne(1L)");
            log.info("--------------------------");
            log.info(repository.findOne(1L).toString());

            //Fetch one User By Name
            log.info("User found with findByName(\"Niek\")");
            log.info("--------------------------");
            for(User user: repository.findByName("Niek")){
                log.info(user.toString());
            }
        };
    }
}
```

I assume some of you are thinking Well you did not implement your repository.

> In a typical Java application, you’d expect to write a class that implements CustomerRepository. But that’s what makes Spring Data JPA so powerful: You don’t have to write an implementation of the repository interface. Spring Data JPA creates an implementation on the fly when you run the application.

Which brings me to my questions:

- Is It because of the repository implementation that Spring Data JPA provides on the fly that it's asking for a property "name" instead of just using the property "userName" which I have provided?
- If the answer to the previous question is "YES", is it safe to assume that providing your own implementation will be far less prone to errors? since it seems the generated implementation seems to work with a certain convention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### While writing out this question I figured out the answer

The answer is fairly simple:

- Yes, because *Spring Data JPA* creates the implementation it does not recognize the property "userName" and asks for the property "name". The simple reason for this is because in the interface I declared the method to be.`public List<User> findByName(String userName)`, apperently there is a naming convention where the property needs to fit the method name. so my method needed to be `public List<User> findByUserName(String userName)`.
- So it is not perticularly preffered to implement the interface yourself, but you need to pay close attention to little conventions like this which I did not find anywhere yet.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to annotate all fields in `User` POJO class. To do so, you have to annotate all fields with `@Column` annotation except for the first one (in this case, it has to be annotated with @Id). Also you have to make sure that, you have all getters/setters for all specified fields.